Можно ли избавиться от постоянных запросов сертификата в OperaMail?
Понимаю, что вроде как устарела программа, но она настолько приятна и быстра, что менять не хочется.
При открытии каждого письма появляется такое окошко

Можно ли это исправить?
Доп. скрины
ScreenShot
ScreenShot
